# Handling JobIntentService and Thread Sleep

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, jobintentservice

**Background:**

Recently I had to migrate a Service to JobIntentService (JIS) for supporting Android 8.0 background service restrictions. This service registers the token with my server after FirebaseInstanceIDService invokes it.

**Problem:**

I have a network call that has to be made from a JobIntentService (JIS). All the network call operations are handled via Eventbus (EB).

The flow is as below

```
JIS -> request API (EB) -> {API Call Handler} -> Send Response (EB) -> JIS -> Handle response.
```

The trouble as you might have guessed is that the moment request API event is fired, the Intent service finishes itself and doesnot handle the response event.

**Temporary Solution:**

The way I've solved this in a dirty way is by calling Thread.sleep(400) immediate after firing the event.(the API takes roughly 150ms to respond)

This makes sure the JIS is still around to handle the response, by the time the API response event reaches.

---

I wanted to confirm if this is the right approach (since it felt like a brute force for me) or whether there is a cleaner approach.

Comment: how do you call your web API? is it retrofit? something else?

Comment: @pskink Yes. Retrofit.

Comment: so use [sync requests](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests)

Comment: @pskink Exactly what I was looking for. This is great. I tested and it works fine. I'm wondering why this doesn't throw the NetworkOnMainThreadException error. Is it because I'm spawning the request inside Intent Service ?

Comment: just Log.d the value of Thread.currentThread(), what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: The thread name says AsyncTask. (And thank for this info. I didn't know one could log the thread name).
@pskink Could you post ur suggestion as an answer so that I can mark it as right ?

Answer (score 0):

In Your JobService you can return true from onStartJob(),It indicates that you have still work to do so the JIS will not finish. once you got the response you can call finishJob() to finish the JIS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I'm using JobIntentService and not JobService. Hence no access to onStartJob() and onFinishJob().

Comment: Ok In that case , you can use CountDownLatch. These are better than Thread.sleep().    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); Call latch.await(); after triggerring your API, once done call latch.countDown();

Comment: Thanks Ankit. TIL about CountDownLatch. This will be my back up plan but I'm going with the solution provided by @pskink since it's cleaner.